# Ubuntu Core and Electron

Tags: ubuntu, electron, snapcraft

I have an electron app which controls some devices over the network.  I was wondering if there is a way to run this app on a Ubuntu Core computer and use the all as the GUI so there is no window manager or anything involved.  On boot it would just start the app.  Is this possible?  How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "the all".

But just a guess, would not NW.JS be better for you? It's got less desktop GUI hooks than electron, more of a basic HTML page approach on the UI side.